# Get a reference of Azure blob by the full Uri not the blob name?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I 'm saving the uri of the file in the database in this form:

```
https://app.blob.core.windows.net/container/Accounts/Images/acc.jpg
```

But to delete it I need to pass only the blob name,
when I try this

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = Container.GetBlockBlobReference(uri);
```

The blob's full `uri` becomes:

`https://app.blob.core.windows.net/container/https://app.blob.core.windows.net/container/Accounts/Images/acc.jpg`

So I get `404` error (not found),
I can do some trimming to the `uri` but that doesn't seem efficient.
so is there a way to delete a blob/ get reference by its full URI?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to do this creating the `CloudBlockBlob` with this [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj682606.aspx):

```
public CloudBlockBlob(Uri blobAbsoluteUri)
```

In your case, assuming uri is of type Uri and not just a string:

```
CloudBlockBlob blob = new CloudBlockBlob(uri);
```

You might need to use your credentials if the blob isn't public or the uri doesn't contain SAS credentials (like to one you included). In that case you will need this [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj682568.aspx):

```
public CloudBlockBlob(Uri blobAbsoluteUri, StorageCredentials credentials)
```

As stated by [Zhaoxing Lu - Microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2995449/zhaoxing-lu-microsoft) on the comments,

> Public access is read only access, you need to specify the storage
>   account key or Shared Access Signature for deleting operation.

Comment: The `Uri` is correct now, but still getting the same 404 error?

Comment: Is the blob/container public?

Comment: Yes, it's public. I tried to trim the Uri and used `GetBlockBlobReference` method, and, somehow, it works

Comment: I tried it on my container and it worked, which method gives you the 404? I tried with `blob.Exists()` without any problem on v8

Comment: `blockBlob.DeleteIfExists();`

Comment: In that case it fails, just like you said. I would report it on github seems it might be a bug (given that `Exists` returns true). `Delete` also throws the same exception.

Comment: It's not a bug. Public access is read only access, you need to specify the storage account key or Shared Access Signature for deleting operation.

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft right, it makes sense. What's strange is that it returns 404 instead of 401

Comment: We don't want to let unauthorized people know if the resource really exists, so Azure Storage FE returns 404 no matter whether the resource exists. You can see 403 (Forbidden) part in https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html : "If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not Found) can be used instead."

Comment: Github does the same thing when you try to access a private repository without credentials. It returns a 404.

Comment: Also to add a note - the credentials can be obtained from the `CloudBlobClient.Credentials` property.

Comment: how would you download the blob just by using the uri?

Answer (score 18):

I did face similar issue , since i already had valid container reference this worked for me  :

```
CloudBlockBlob blockblob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(new CloudBlockBlob(blobUri).Name);
```

Comment: so what if we dont know the container without looking at the entire URI like `https://xxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/input/DisabledFlights[1].cache` and in this case the container is `input` ive asked a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57080549/getting-a-reference-to-a-blob-using-its-uri-from-the-portal

Comment: I took more than 1 hour to find it :p. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can now use the `BlobUriBuilder` class to safely get the blob name from the URI without the need for string parsing or other methods.

```cs
BlobUriBuilder blobUriBuilder = new BlobUriBuilder(new Uri(blobUri));
var sourceBlob = container.GetBlobClient(blobUriBuilder.BlobName);
```

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is that you're putting the URI string inside the blob name with this function `GetBlockBlobReference` as defined: `public virtual CloudBlockBlob GetBlockBlobReference(string blobName);`. You will use moondaisy solution's.