# Getting a reference to a blob using its URI

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

**How do we get a blob reference via URI?**

I'm getting a reference to a blob like so:

```
        var blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri("https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/input/DisabledFlights[1].cache"));
```

The way I got this URL, is through the portal:

[image]

When attempting to download it:

```
            await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
[7/17/2019 4:25:27 PM] Executed 'sFtpSender' (Failed, Id=4943c931-5850-4dc8-abe4-c111ed6bbfa9)
[7/17/2019 4:25:27 PM] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: sFtpSender. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: The specified resource does not exist.
```

**What am I doing wrong? How do I get a reference to a blob?**

Comment: You'll need to use the `CloudStorageAccount` type to create a `CloudBlobClient`, and from there you can get the container reference or Blob Reference (see the API for whatever meets your needs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error message, I think the blob is in private container.

There're 2 methods for get a blob reference using its uri.

**Method 1**: Change the container Access Level to Blob level or Container level, then you can directly use the code below:

```
var blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri("https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/input/DisabledFlights[1].cache"));

await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);
```

**Method 2**:If you want to keep the container as private, when initiate a `CloudBlockBlob()`, you should specify `StorageCredentials` within it, like below:

```
//besides using sas token, you can also use other way to construct StorageCredentials, like using account_name / account_key.
var blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri("https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/input/DisabledFlights[1].cache"), ,new StorageCredentials("sasToken"));

await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var blobName = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri("https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/input/DisabledFlights[1].cache")).Name;

CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = _container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
```

where `_container` is `CloudBlobContainer`
then

```
await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);
```